# Kendo Grid pagenation count not working on default with local data

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo grid pagenation count not working on default page load, after clicking some button it gets updated automatically. how to make it work on initial load itself ?

**For reference :** [image: Pagenation on page default load] , [image: After PageNation Button Click]

HTML:

```
<div id="custGrid" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"></div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [{"slNo":"1","upOn":"15-Aug-2016","fileName":"reconciliation.csv"},{"slNo":"2","upOn":"14-Aug-2016","fileName":"report.csv"},{"slNo":"3","upOn":"12-Aug-2016","fileName":"reconReport.csv"}];
    $('#custGrid').kendoGrid({
        "columnMenu" : true,
        "dataSource" : data,
        "filterable" : true,
        "sortable" : true,
        "pageable" : true,
        "columns" : [ {
            "field" : "slNo",
            "title" : "Sl No."
        }, {
            "field" : "upOn",
            "title" : "Uploaded On"
        }, {
            "field" : "fileName",
            "title" : "File Name"
        } ],
        "scrollable" : {},
        "excel" : {
            "allPages" : true,
            "fileName" : "Tasks.xls"
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is enough for pointing local data:

```
dataSource : {
    data: data, 
    pageSize: 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working dojo for you. http://dojo.telerik.com/oVELa

If you are paging then you need to provide the datasource a pagesize. as per the [api docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-pageSize).

all I have done is expanded out your datasource element from dataSource:data  to

```
 dataSource : {
          data: data, 
          pageSize: 10,
          schema:
          {
            model: {
               fields:{
                 slNo: {type:"number"},
                 upOn: {type:"datetime"},
                 fileName: {type:"string"},
               }
            }
          }
        },
```

I personally find this more useful than just point it to the array as it gives you a bit more info of what should be happening with the data provided to the grid.

If you need anything else give me a shout.

Comment: actually mentioning the pageSize alone is working fine... does the schema actually required here ?

Comment: No it's not required but I like to have the data expanded out so that it is easier to read and when something isn't working as expected I can check to see if something is missing/mis-configured.